# Boolean Simplification of AB + A'+B'

Tags: functional-equations, boolean-algebra

Is there any way to simplify this function? Or is this the simplest equation? : `AB + A'+B'`

Comment: Can you use "exclusive-or" (xor)?

Comment: Can you check the question again Mr. Kennytm? I updated it.

Comment: I think this is the result : f= f'' = A.B

Comment: Was there a mistake in the previous function?  The answer to the current question by the way is $1$.

Comment: Yeah I did a mistake. Corrected. Can you prove the result equals 1 Mike?

Comment: Did you try anything at all? What was the simplest you got?

Comment: Now I think I got the answer. The result is 1. Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general technique in boolean algebra is to add or multiply some term by "$P+P$'" to make it similar to other terms so that they can be simplified. In this case:

$AB+A'(B+B')+B'$

$=(A+A')B+A'B'+B'$

$=B+A'B'+(A+A')B'$

$=B+A'B'+AB'+A'B'$

$=B+A'B'+AB'$

$=B+(A+A')B'$

$=B+B'$.

But in complicated cases it may not simplify immediately.

Note that this solution uses only identity, inverse, idempotency and distributivity and so avoids using De Morgan's laws unlike the other solutions. De Morgan's laws, which are extremely useful of course, can be proven in a similar way if desired. Alternatively one can use truth tables to verify all basic rules.

Answer (score 4):

$$AB+A'+B' = AB+ \overline{AB} = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$0\cdot0+1+1=1\\1\cdot0+0+1=1\\0\cdot1+1+0=1\\1\cdot1+0+0=1$$

Answer (score 1):

```
F = AB + A'+B'
F' = (A'+B').AB = A'AB + ABB' = 0
```

Again if I take `F = F'' = 1` , 1 will the the result.

Comment: I don't see how you got the inverse. What rule did you use?

Comment: I inverted the equation two times. So this means it equals itself. F = F''

Comment: Oh okay then it is correct!

Comment: Yes that works !

Answer (score 1):

AB + A' + B'

Expand missing terms.

AB + A' (B' + B) + B' (A' + A) - Complement Law

AB + A'B' + A'B + A'B' + AB'

Eliminate duplicates and rearrange.

A'B' + A'B + AB' + AB

A' (B' + B) + A (B' + B) - Complement Law

A' + A

1

http://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm